# Link error for static member variable.in template struct

Tags: c++, templates, static

I'm a bit curious about what is special about template struct members. In particular, it seems I'm unable to define uninitialized static members in template classes/structs.

Notice that the following snippet does not link, with an undefined reference to `Struct<int>::member`

```
template <typename T>
struct Struct {
  static T member;
};
template <typename T>
T foo(T t) {
  return Struct<T>::member = t;
}

template struct Struct<int>;
template <>
int Struct<int>::member;

int main() {
  return foo(1);
}
```

However, the seemingly-equivalent

```
struct StructInt {
   static int member;
};
int foo(int t) {
   return StructInt::member = t;
}

int StructInt::member;

int main() {
   return foo(1);
}
```

compiles with no errors.

Comment: Any reason why you are not using `template <typename T> T Struct<T>::member;
`?

Comment: In this particular case, I happen to know exactly what types will be used with the template, though I suppose that would work as well. Does this solve the link error?

Comment: Yes, it certainly does.

Comment: Ah, that's the answer then. If you want to write that up, I'll accept it.

Comment: I am hesitant because I am not sure what the lines `template struct Struct<int>;
template <>
int Struct<int>::member;` in your posted code to.

Comment: The first line explicitly instantiates the struct, similar to if it had been used in a function

Comment: The second, I'm guessing, is interpreted as a forward declaration of  a specialization of one of its members. I had intended it to be a definition

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183224/discussion-between-r-sahu-and-tyg13).

Answer (score 1):

It seems the line(s)

```
template <>
int Struct<int>::member;
```

just declare the variable, not define it. Changing it to

```
template <>
int Struct<int>::member = 0;
```

resolves the linker error.

You can also use

```
template <typename T>
T Struct<T>::member;
```

to resolve the linker error.

Comment: In this case, I actually wanted to avoid initializing the value. Your original answer of using `template <typename T> T Struct<T>::member;` was what I was looking for.